# One WP Plugin shortcode attribute changes properly, the other one sticks to the first-passed value across whole site

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

This is a Wordpress with PHP/React Plugin.

There are two attributes that are supposed to be given to the plugin via the shortcode: `lang` and `formType`. There are multiple instances of the plugin across the site: page 1, page 2, etc.

Say I load page 1, which has the plugin with attributes `lang=lang1` and `formType=type1`. So far, everything works as expected.

I then load page 2, which has the plugin with attributes `lang=lang2`and `formType=type2`. On this page, it loads the plugin with the correct language, but it uses `formType=type1`. This is reflected in the HTML element that the PHP loads the attributes into for the React app to read from.

I tried on a different Wordpress site that uses Autoptimize and Breeze for caching. I clear those caches and try to load page 2 again, and it still uses `formType=type1`.

If page 2 is loaded first, then page 1 will use `formType=type2`.

There is also a `plugin_name_dev` shortcode which is exactly the same except it can be configured to load different .js and .css assets. If, at this stage, I load page 3 with the `plugin_name_dev` shortcode with `lang1` and `type1` attributes, it will load properly.

If I then load page 4 with the dev version and attributes `lang2` and `type2`, it will load the plugin with `lang2` and `type1`.

In case it helps, this is what the code of the shortcode looks like:

```
add_shortcode('plugin_name', function ($atts) {
    $args = shortcode_atts([
        'lang' => 'lang1',
        'formType' => 'type2'
    ], $atts);
    return plugin_name_shortcode($args['lang'], $args['formType']);
});
```

And this is the code for the `plugin_name_shortcode(...)`:

```
function plugin_name_shortcode($lang = 'lang1', $formType = 'type2')
{
    $config = load_config();
    $country = detect_country();
    $config['country'] = $country;

    wp_enqueue_style('plugin-name-style');
    wp_enqueue_script('plugin-name-script');
    wp_localize_script(
        'plugin-name-script',
        'businessConfig',
        $config
    );

    return make_plugin_html($lang, $formType);
}
```

What I've tried

- Tinkering with `.htaccess` (the server uses Apache) to not allow caching for `.js` files and confirmed that the resulting `.js` file downloaded has "max-age=0".
- Renaming the `formType` attribute

**Edit:** Added info about `plugin_name_dev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into something similar, I ended up solving this by changing formType to formtype. The capital T seemed to mess it up.